# SQLiteOpenHelper на новых версиях API

Tags: android, sqlite

Третий день ищу решение, есть приложение в котором используется `SQLiteOpenHelper`, и которое нормально работает на версиях андроида начиная с 15, но на новых встречаются проблемы. Главной особенностью является факт того что на некоторых устройствах может нормально работать и на седьмом андроиде, а на некоторых уже на пятом отказуется. На эмуляторе, последняя рабочая версия это API19.

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: tracking
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tracking (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO tracking(lng,battery_level,bearing,alt,satcnt,lat,speed,timepoint) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
    at com.my.app.db.DbProvider.insert(DbProvider.java:538)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:265)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:152)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

В чём может быть проблема и куда копать?
P.S. разрешение WriteExternal есть.

UPD: helper:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    if(!checkDataBase()) {
        createTables(db);
    }
}

 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    AppLog.i("Old db version: " + oldVersion + ", new version: " + newVersion);

    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        try {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.TravelTotals.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.TripInfo.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Goods.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Outlets.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Route.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Doctypes.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Distrtypes.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.VarReasons.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Statuses.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.DocH.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.DocD.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Messages.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Tracking.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.DayTasks.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.DataStatus.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBH.Survey.TABLE_NAME);

            createTables(db);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.e("Db upgrade error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private boolean isTableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName)
{
    if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen()) {
        return false;
    }

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='" + tableName + "'", null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int count = cursor.getInt(0);
            cursor.close();
            return count > 0;
        }
        else {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName, Field[] flds, Field[] tps, String foreign)
{
    if (!isTableExists(db, tableName))
    {
        AppLog.e("Create table: " + "!isTableExists"+tableName);
        String sql = "create table " + tableName + " (";

        for (int i = 0; i < flds.length; i++) {

            try {
                sql = sql + flds[i].get(DBH.class).toString() + " " + tps[i].get(DBH.class).toString();
                if (i != flds.length - 1) {
                    sql = sql + ", ";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                AppLog.e("Create table error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        sql = sql + (foreign == null ? ")" : (", " + foreign + ")"));
        AppLog.i("Query table creation: " + sql);

        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.e("Create table error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    createTable(db, DBH.TravelTotals.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.TravelTotals.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.TravelTotals.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.TripInfo.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.TripInfo.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.TripInfo.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Goods.TABLE_NAME,      DBH.Goods.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Goods.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Outlets.TABLE_NAME,    DBH.Outlets.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Outlets.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Route.TABLE_NAME,      DBH.Route.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Route.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Doctypes.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.Doctypes.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Doctypes.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Distrtypes.TABLE_NAME, DBH.Distrtypes.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Distrtypes.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.VarReasons.TABLE_NAME, DBH.VarReasons.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.VarReasons.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Statuses.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.Statuses.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Statuses.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.DocH.TABLE_NAME,       DBH.DocH.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.DocH.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.DocD.TABLE_NAME,       DBH.DocD.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.DocD.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Messages.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.Messages.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Messages.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Tracking.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.Tracking.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Tracking.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.DayTasks.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.DayTasks.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.DayTasks.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.DataStatus.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.DataStatus.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.DataStatus.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    createTable(db, DBH.Survey.TABLE_NAME,   DBH.Survey.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.Survey.DT.class.getFields(), null);
}

private boolean checkDataBase()
{ 
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mDbName, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("SQLiteHelper", "Error sqlite = " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return (checkDB != null);
}
```

Comment: А при чём тут *разрешение WriteExternal*, у вас база в нестандартном расположении? Не мешало бы показать код хелпера.

Comment: @woesss, в стандартном. Какая вас часть интересует? Тут почти на тыщу строк.

Comment: Как-то смущает проверка `checkDataBase()` - метод `onCreate()` в принципе  вызывается системой только если бд не существует. Но на момент вызова она уже создана и результат этой проверки не непонятен. Я удивляюсь, что оно вообще где-то работает.

Comment: @woess, знаете, я думал это я чего то не понимаю, имею мало опыта с этой библиотекой ибо она мне никогда особо не нравилась. checkDatabase() вызывается только в onCreate(). Возможно у вас есть какие-нибудь идеи? P.S. была бы немного другая реализация, я бы переделал на Room или Realm, но проект большой, там более двухсот мест использования этого хелпера... И всё достаточно путанно.

Comment: Так я не вижу смысла в этой проверке - предлагаю убрать её и вызывать `createTables()` безусловно. Потому что если `onCreate()` вызван, то таблиц в базе 100% нет. Второй сомнительный момент в `onUpgrade()`: `createTables()` вызывается в конце `try`-блока - если вдруг выпадет ошибка, то после такого апгрэйда в базе останутся только таблицы, до которых удаление не дошло.

Comment: @woesss, то есть вы предлагаете вынести createTables() в блок: finally{}? Некоторые таблицы не удалятся, то как себя поведёт этот метод? И если наша таблица не поменяется, и мы попытаемся туда внести данные из толбцов которых не существует, или такой вариант исключён из-за пересоздания таблицы?

Comment: Насчёт апгрейда думайте сами - я не знаю что у вас за база и как она должна работать, а значит и по какой логике обновляться. В теории ошибка при выполнении `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` - это очень экзотический случай и, возможно, никогда не случится.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо убрал проверку, и перенёс в финалли метод createTables(). Работает. Буду наблюдать за поведением. Если есть желание, оформите ответ, я его прийму как решение.